# Liferay 7 ignores AssetEntryQuery parameters

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

AssetEntryQuery is ignoring all the parameters I set, thus executing a wildcard query and retrieving all my asset entries.

Snippet of what I'm doing right now:

```
long[] classTypeIds = new long[] { 30837 };

AssetEntryQuery assetQuery = new AssetEntryQuery();
assetQuery.setClassTypeIds(classTypeIds);

List<AssetEntry> entries = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.getEntries(assetQuery);

foreach (AssetEntry entry : entries) {
    System.out.printf("Entry with classTypeId %d expected %d", entry.getClassTypeId(), 30837);
}
```

When I execute this code, it returns a List of ALL the entries from liferay without their classTypeId being filtered.

**Output:**

```
[...]
Entry with classTypeId 0 expected 30837
Entry with classTypeId 0 expected 30837
Entry with classTypeId 28920 expected 30837
Entry with classTypeId 30331 expected 30837
Entry with classTypeId 30837 expected 30837
Entry with classTypeId 30837 expected 30837
Entry with classTypeId 30837 expected 30837
Entry with classTypeId 30921 expected 30837
[...]
```

Am I missing something so Liferay is ignoring my AssetEntryQuery params or is it a bug within Liferay itself?

Comment: I'm curious about your case. The code is recognizing that there's different `classTypeId`s (so it's not related to the value of 0 being persisted in the DB, as I mentioned in my answer below). If `classNameId` isn't good for your use case, I'd recommend trying to post on the Liferay forums. https://web.liferay.com/community/forums

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's intentional or not (probably not), but in the `assetentry` table of my DB (I'm only looking at it for dev purposes, as it's never recommended to do anything directly to the DB), the `classtypeid` field is `0` for all entries in my build of the latest `liferay-portal` master branch. This is just a shot in the dark, but you could try calling

`AssetEntryQuery.setClassNameIds`

instead of `setClassTypeIds`, and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Russ. As far as I understand classTypeId is used to link AssetEntries with DDMs, and classNameId is used to link AssetEntries with their backing class (JournalArticle, DLFileEntry, etc...), so it won't fix the issue. Do you know where to report bugs to liferay? their issue tracker (http://issues.liferay.com/) has closed signups.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what `classTypeId` was for, but I suppose that makes sense. `classNameID` is meant to associate the asset entry (in this case) with the backing class, as you said.